# resampling mp3 file from 44.1 KHz to 48 KHz by matlab (creating my own resampling function)

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to upsample (resample) a mp3 file (fs = 44.1 KHz) to 48 KHz and write it as a wav file with matlab.
I read the file and then took FFT but I do not know that how to add zero in frequency domain. in fact I have write my own resample function
would you please help me about above mentioned problem :

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('piano.mp3');

left=y(:,1); % entire rows and first column

time=(1/44100)*length(left);

t=linspace(0,time,abs(length(left)));
stem(t,abs(left));

%% fft %%

y1= fft(y(:,1));
left1=y1(:,1); % all rows and first column

time1=(1/44100)*length(left1);

t1=linspace(0,time1,abs(length(left1)));

stem(t1,abs(left1));

***%% ???? place to add zero ??***


%% fftshift(fft(x))%%

y1= fftshift(fft(y(:,1)));
left1=y1(:,1); % all rows and first column
time1=(1/44100)*length(left1); 
t1=linspace(0,time1,abs(length(left1)));
plot(t,left)
```

Comment: Any reason not to use the resample function?

Comment: are you trying to recreate `resample` ?

Comment: as this is an assignment so I am not allowed to use matlab built in function such as resample().

Comment: yes i suppose to recreate resample.

Comment: hint: http://dspguru.com/dsp/howtos/how-to-interpolate-in-time-domain-by-zero-padding-in-frequency-domain

Answer (score 0):

You need a low pass filter in between the upsample and downsample stages to get rid of the aliasing that would occur otherwise. This functionality is built into the matlab resample function.

[Link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/resampling.html#brbq7ll)

Comment: as this is an assignment so I am not allowed to use matlab built in function such as resample().